# How to use http and https proxy together in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in scrapy. I found that for use http proxy but I want to use http and https proxy together because when I crawl the links there has http and https links. How do I use also http and https proxy?

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT"
        #like here request.meta['proxy'] = "https://YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT"
        proxy_user_pass = "USERNAME:PASSWORD"
        # setup basic authentication for the proxy
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use standard environment variables with the combination of the [HttpProxyMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy):

> This middleware sets the HTTP proxy to use for requests, by setting the proxy meta value for Request objects.
>
> Like the Python standard library modules urllib and urllib2, it obeys the following environment variables:
>
> ```
> http_proxy
> https_proxy
> no_proxy
> ```
>
> You can also set the meta key proxy per-request, to a value like http://some_proxy_server:port.

Comment: Thank you, but i have 100 more proxies. So how can i set them, please advise.

Comment: In this case look at the request URL and decide to use HTTP or HTTPS as proxy -- and choose one of your 100+ available (or if all are HTTPS capable then add a `s` after the `http` in the `reques.meta['proxy']` assignment.