# Right way of using http proxy and https proxy within meta while using http site and https sites individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy

I've been trying for the last couple of hours to find out any specific guidance on how to use `http` and `https` proxies respectively within `meta['proxy']`. Let us consider the two urls `http://app1.nu.edu.bd/` and `https://www.yelp.com/` where I wish to use `http` proxy and `https` proxy individually as the protocol are different. For this very example we can think of using the two type of proxies 1. http proxy - `62.210.99.150:3838` and 2. https proxy - `173.212.202.65:80`.

Now, I'm trying like the following:

While using `http://app1.nu.edu.bd/`:

```
meta['proxy'] = 'http://173.212.202.65:80'
```

while going for `https://www.yelp.com/`:

```
meta['proxy'] = 'https://62.210.99.150:3838'
```

What is the right way to use `http` proxy and `https` proxy within meta while using `http` site and `https` sites individually?

Note: Before creating my post above, I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313760/how-to-use-http-and-https-proxy-together-in-scrapy) few times where there is a very different question asked. As the titles are a bit similar, so I thought to clarify this in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to do that (you can use middleware or use `request['meta']`):

```
proxy = 'http://173.212.202.65:80'
if your_target_url.startswith("https"):
    proxy = 'https://62.210.99.150:3838'
yield scrapy.Request(
    url=your_target_url,
    callback=self.your_callback,
    meta={
        'proxy': proxy,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing it, using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, should look like this:

```
import requests

PROXIES = {
 "http": 'http://173.212.202.65:80',
 "https": 'https://62.210.99.150:3838',
}

http_url = "http://app1.nu.edu.bd/"
https_url = "https://www.yelp.com/"

response = requests.get(https_url, proxies=PROXIES)
```